# Change cursor position in textbox in C# Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor

I have a winform which load MDI child winform. All textboxes in child winform always have cursor stay at left side and I can't move it to another position, except I choose all text and re-input.

How can I enable this to make cursor can stay at any position by using mouse?

Comment: For each TextBox try SelectionStart = i and SelectionLength = 0, where i is the desired cursor position.

Comment: How can I set for all textboxs? Cause' I have a lot of textboxs :(

Comment: Use a loop :) Forms have a property called Controls, which is a ControlCollection. You can iterate over its elements using `foreach (var c in form.Controls)`, test whether the current control is a TextBox using `TextBox tb = c as TextBox; if (tb != null) ...` and set the cursor position for `tb`.

Comment: It means there are no way to set this. Ex a property of win form? We must do this manually :(

Answer (score 12):

In the following example the cursor will be positioned after the second character in each textbox of the form. The focus will be on the last one, but by pressing the TAB key repeatedly, you can verify that the cursor position has been set for every textbox.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var form = new Form();
    form.Text = "Cursor Positioning Test";
    form.Visible = true;
    form.Shown += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) {
      foreach (var control in form.Controls)
      {
        var textBox = control as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
          textBox.Focus();
          textBox.SelectionStart = 2;
          textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
      }
    };

    var textBox1 = new TextBox();
    textBox1.Text = "hello";
    textBox1.Left = 10;
    textBox1.Top = 10;
    form.Controls.Add(textBox1);

    var textBox2 = new TextBox();
    textBox2.Text = "stack";
    textBox2.Left = 10;
    textBox2.Top = 10 + textBox1.Height + 10;
    form.Controls.Add(textBox2);

    var textBox3 = new TextBox();
    textBox3.Text = "overflow";
    textBox3.Left = 10;
    textBox3.Top = 10 + textBox1.Height + 10 + textBox2.Height + 10;
    form.Controls.Add(textBox3);

    Application.Run(form);
  }
}
```

Comment: kol, great, but won't it work if you do the following with the foreach:
foreach (TextBox control in form.Controls), then you won't need this:
var textBox = control as TextBox; 

Note that I haven't tested it yet, but I think it should work.

Comment: @PavelDonchev Your idea works only if all controls are TextBoxes. If you also have a Button on the form, then you will get an exception saying System.Windows.Forms.Button cannot be converted to System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.

Comment: I am not quite sure you are right.
I just created a form with a button and a text box, then wrote the following:
foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls)
{
    MessageBox.Show(tb.Name);
}

And had no problems to execute it and get the name of the textbox on the form, it simply skipped the button.
Very interested if it doesn't work for you - why it doesn't work.
I tried it on a Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (the default settings for me). Sorry for having to write code in the comments, I know it won't appear fine.

Comment: @PavelDonchev I tested your idea with the above code, with two modifications: (1) added a button (`var button = new Button(); form.Controls.Add(button);`), and (2) changed the `form.Shown` event handler delegate to `foreach (TextBox textBox in form.Controls) { textBox.Focus(); textBox.SelectionStart = 2; textBox.SelectionLength = 0; }`. The latter throws the exception I mentioned above.

Comment: You are right.
Now I noticed why did it trick me.
In the Shown event handler the process gets killed (Visual Studio pops up if you are debugging, showing you the line with the Invalid Cast Exception).
If you try to put the code in the Load event handler you will notice that the form will normally load (except it won't work as expected). If you put the code in try .. catch block you will still be able to catch the InvalidCastException. Pretty strange behavior.

Answer (score 9):

Try This , Hope Helps You ;)

```
//if you want put cusror at the end of text use this:
TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length;
TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
//use this for custom location  int CustomIndex 
TextBox1.SelectionStart = CustomIndex;
TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

//Windows forms maskedTextBox Input Right to Left testex with '##.####' mask decimal(6,4);

private void maskedTextBoxMaskRTF_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

```
        var maskedTextBox = (MaskedTextBox)sender;

        var contLit = maskedTextBox.Text.Where(ch => ".,".Contains(ch)).Count();

        var value = maskedTextBox.Text.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "") + e.KeyChar;

        if (value.Length >= maskedTextBox.Mask.Length - contLit)
            value = value.Substring(1);
        else
            while (value.Length < maskedTextBox.Mask.Length - contLit)
                value = "_" + value;

        maskedTextBox.Text = value;
        maskedTextBox.SelectionStart = maskedTextBox.Mask.Length - 1;
        maskedTextBox.SelectionLength = 1;           
    }
```