# Moving the cursor to the end after changing numbers containing thousands separator

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my user to input an amount in textbox with a "text_change event".

I use this code

```
txtamount.Text = (double.Parse(txtamount.Text)).ToString("N0");
```

to separate thousand with comma.

The problem is every time user input thousand eg. 1400 it display exactly 1,400 but the input line is infront like |1,400. I want the input line to be like 1,400| to continue user input.

Comment: You should rethink what you are asking about. There is absolutely nothing special about decimal separator in your post... In current state it can't be even be closed with duplicate that answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206723/change-cursor-position-in-textbox-in-c-sharp-windows

Comment: Thanks Jeff for changing the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
textBox1.Text = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString("N0");
textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
```

But, if the user arrows back to the left and starts to type it leads to an unpleasant user experience.

Trying to format numbers while the user is typing them never seems to work out.

Comment: I am curious - Is there an elegant solution to allow it?

Comment: Thanks Steve for this perfect code. It really solve my problem. :)