# C# How to set text in caret position of textbox

Tags: c#, caret, cursor-position

How can I set text in **Caret Position** (cursor position) of textbox by `Click` on button?

I can set text end of textbox but I need to set some text in cursor location by clicking on some buttons like below:

[image: Caret Position]

Comment: Where do you want the caret to be placed?

Comment: Probably something like `textBox1.SelectionLength = 0; textBox1.SelectedText = "New text";`. You forgot to mention what kind of TextBox is that (what UI Platform).

Comment: `TextBox1.SelectionStart = yourCursorLocation; TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0; TextBox1.Focus()`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167951/5446495, too many answers on SO you can find for selection

Comment: @NathanChampion user selected location

Comment: @AndrewMorton how can i get cursorLocation in textbox?

Comment: I think the question is, when the "Brand" button is clicked, how do I put the cursor in front of the "Brand" text?

Comment: @LarsTech No, when the "Brand" button clicked, should put "{Brand}" text in cursor location of textbox. for example cursor is between of 2 words and after click should "{Brand}" text paste between of 2 words (cursor location)

Comment: @Jimi Thank You, but i need to get cursor location after click on button and set text in this location. my platform is winform

Comment: `textBox1.SelectedText = "{Brand}";` ?

Comment: @Genusatplay Dear, i need to get location of cursor in textbox and paste (set) text in this location

Comment: @LarsTech Thank You Dear, My problem is solved with your code ;-)

Comment: That's exactly what I posted does. The Caret position doesn't change when you click a Button, so the text will be inserted where the Caret currently is. `textBox1.SelectionLength = 0` is to remove a selection and just add text in the current position. If you want to replace a selection, then just remove `textBox1.SelectionLength = 0`.

Comment: another way.. with replace  `var newText = "SomeBrand"; var result = "{Type {Brand}".Replace(" {Brand}", $" {newText} {{Brand}}");` clumsy but works

Comment: @Jimi Thank You Dear, Your description is complete and helpful